# SSL error in CURL call to Twitter API

Tags: php, curl, twitter, zend-framework2

Below is some code of my controller (dont worry, de keys are fake). Im using the ZendService\Twitter\Twitter module. Almost everything is working only the last error is a bit strange and i can not figure it out:

`Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection api.twitter.com: make sure the "sslcafile" or "sslcapath" option are properly set for the environment.`

As you can see i the code below of my controller, you can see that both the Verify of Peer and Host are set to false. The adapter is already set to Curl instead of HTTP.

```
<?php

namespace Twitter\Controller;

use QDCore\Controller\AbstractController;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use ZendService\Twitter\Twitter;

class GetController extends AbstractController
{

    protected $instance;

    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $config = array(
            'access_token' => array(
                'token' => '1024003resagsDQGyVC5YZ23423PpBNOwefS',
                'secret' => 'oES8Jergewagewahsh2hTqrYGDJo',
            ),
            'oauth_options' => array(
                'consumerKey' => 'QY360Nersehr234gg4aV2pw',
                'consumerSecret' => 'eEfgdagewa0Hkt4z6nCqHPY1M4wwuubY',
            ),
            'username' => 'myusername',
            'http_client_options' => array(
                'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
                'curloptions' => array(
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                ),
            ),
        );
        $this->instance = new Twitter($config);
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $result = new JsonModel(array('message' => 'No valid function call made'));
        return $result;
    }

    public function usertimelineAction()
    {
        $options = array(
            'user_id' => 'myaccountname',
            'count' => 30,
        );
        $twitter = new Twitter($options);
        $response = $twitter->statuses->userTimeline();
        var_dump($response);
        die;
        return new JsonModel($response);
    }
}
```

Hope that someone has an idea on how to fix it. My main domain is not running on SSL and is not going to be.

Thanks

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298282/php-and-ssl-ca-verification-os-independent

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** set verify host or peer verification to false, unless you know what you are doing!

You have to point curl to your certification bundle. For Linux (Debian based systems) that is `etc/ssl/certs`. You could set that as "sslcapath" variable:

```
'http_client_options' => array(
    'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(
        'sslcapath' => '/etc/ssl/certs',
    ),
),
```

Because the path varies between systems, it's good to have it as an option set in your `config/autoload/global.php` file which users could change with a `local.php` configuration. In your config:

```
'http_client' => array(
    'options' => array(
        'sslcapath' => '/etc/ssl/certs',
    ),
),
```

Then your code becomes:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();
    $cnf = $sm->get('Config');

    $config = array(
        'access_token' => array(
            'token' => '1024003resagsDQGyVC5YZ23423PpBNOwefS',
            'secret' => 'oES8Jergewagewahsh2hTqrYGDJo',
        ),
        'oauth_options' => array(
            'consumerKey' => 'QY360Nersehr234gg4aV2pw',
            'consumerSecret' => 'eEfgdagewa0Hkt4z6nCqHPY1M4wwuubY',
        ),
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'http_client_options' => array(
            'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
            'curloptions' => $cnf['http_client']['options'],
        ),
    );
    $this->instance = new Twitter($config);
    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

Comment: Setting the above has the exact same result

Comment: Can you check if the options are set in the HTTP client? Just with some var_dump() statements and how the Twitter service is passing on the options. There might be something wrong there. Usually, setting this option in the HTTP client just works.

Comment: @Dirkos you exposed consumer secret. IMMEDIATELY change it

Comment: Its all fake data dont worry :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and found this on Google. I understood I should either disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` or specify the [correct path to the local certificates](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go), but didn't know how to do that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124135/722036) has helped me a lot:

```
$config = array(
    'callbackUrl' => 'http://example.com/callback.php',
    'siteUrl' => 'http://twitter.com/oauth',
    'consumerKey' => 'myConsumerKey',
    'consumerSecret' => 'myConsumerSecret'
);
$consumer = new ZendOAuth\Consumer($config);

// this is the key:
$adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
$adapter = $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$adapter = $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$httpClient = $consumer->getHttpClient();
$httpClient->setAdapter($adapter);

// now finally fetch a request token
$token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
```